# css help guys :) Надо сделать чистый бекграунд на hovere(убрать сетку таблицы)

Tags: hover

При ховере убрать сетку таблицы [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: html]

[image: hover]

Comment: Приложите код для начала

Comment: добавил, до этого делал на дивах все отлично а как убрать сетку таблицы я не знаю css команды пробывал list-style:none не работает(

Answer (score 1):

```
table, tbody, tr, td, th {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```